# I need to run a program after the Windows Vista Installer Completes. (Windows AIK)

Tags: windows-vista, windows-installer, waik, wim, windows

How can I run a program **after** the Windows Installer? I know how to mount and commit `.wim` files.

This must be done using the `Windows Automated Installation Kit`.

Is there a `default registry hive` where I can create a entry under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run`? where do I find the hive on the installation media?

I don't need to automate the install process, except to run a program after the installer finishes.

**Update:** I just found out about the file `%WINDIR%\Setup\Scripts\SetupComplete.cmd` is this the proper way? Which `.wim` file is this in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If possible I would highly suggest the use of the MDT2010 package as WAIK has been superseded.

Just because scripted installs and automation are possible with MDT doesn't mean you have to use them - for a long time I simply had a basic OS install with no automation and a couple executables in the post install section.